# Sticky Menu stick to bottom instead the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, sticky

I want to create sticky menu but it stay at the bottom. I tried to edit the .menu.sticky position from fixed to other but it just stay. the only position that working is on fixed but it just stick to the bottom of the screen. I tried to edit the js but its not even change. idk what is wrong with my current code

```
.menu {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.menu.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 999;
}

.logo {
    display: none;
}

.logo.sticky {
    display: block;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

nav.sticky .logo {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 30px;
}

nav a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.logo img {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #ffeb3b;
}

a.offer {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ed1f24;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

a.active {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

and here is my JS

```
   <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
        myFunction();
    };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("menu");
    var sticky = menu.offsetTop
    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky + 400) {
            logo.style.display = "block";
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            logo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
    <div class="logo" id="logo" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav-ul">
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabungan">Tabungan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#kredit">Kredit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#deposito">Deposito</a></li>
            <li><a href="#berita">Berita</a></li>
            <li><a class="offer" href="#pengajuan-kredit">Pengajuan Kredit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position property of the .menu.sticky class to absolute. To make the menu stay at the bottom, add the following properties to the same class: bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0.

updated CSS for you:

```
.menu.sticky {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
display: flex;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: i find the problem after read your solutions. I delete the bottom position and change it into top. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have might be because of your javascript.
 You are calling the function before you defined it.

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
// I would also declare those inside the function
    var navbar = document.getElementById("menu");
    var sticky = menu.offsetTop
    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
//then you put your logic
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky + 400) {
            logo.style.display = "block";
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            logo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
//Finally, here you can call your function.
    window.onscroll = function() {
        myFunction();
    };

</script>
```